# Can't set up Unity on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, 18.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and I do not like the Gnome desktop environment. I know that to switch back to unity you have to install ubuntu-unity-desktop and select "Unity (default)" at login, but it doesn't work.

What happens is that I still end up in Gnome, even though I selected Unity. However, this problem seems confined to the **root** user (which is the user I normally use), since I can successfully log in to other accounts in Unity. How do I fix that? In which log file should I look to find the problem?

(I have been using **root** to log in to Unity for years now so don't try to talk me out of it).

Comment: Have you tried both `gdm` and `lightdm` to log in as `root`?

Comment: I did now (had to freshly install Ubuntu 18.04 and set gdm as default display manager) and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start with a 1604 installation with Unity, then upgrade/dist-upgrade it to 1804.

Comment: The question was solved a year ago in comments but no one posted the answer.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Then you can post it as an answer and accept it after two days.

Comment: Only `nc404` can accept an answer and who knows if they will every sign on again?