# Please login as the user “ubuntu” rather than the user “root”

Tags: 18.04, permissions, ssh, login, amazon-ec2

I launched an Ubuntu 18 instance on EC2.

I connected to the server using ubuntu user.

I created a new user named newuser and added it to the sudo group.

Then I ran:

```
rsync --archive --chown=newuser:newuser ~/.ssh /home/newuser
```

in order to let the new user to connect to the server directly.

When I'm trying to connect to the server using the new user I'm getting the following error:

> Using username "newuser".
>
> Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
>
> Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".

I get the same error from both MobaXterm and PuTTY.

Comment: Is there a `~/.ssh/config` file that may be setting the remote user to `root` for SSH?

Comment: @steeldriver no, there is one file in ~/.ssh/ which its name is authorized_keys

Comment: Related [can't sign on as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037628/cant-set-up-unity-on-ubuntu-18-04/1157101)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As tritium_3 suggested, I had to edit .ssh/authorized_keys, to remove the following text:

```
no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user \"ubuntu\" rather than the user \"root\".';echo;sleep 10"
```

and keep the ssh-rsa and key that comes after it.

However, the `rsync` command had copied the file to the new user, so I had to edit the file that was under /home/newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys rather than /root/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: Yes, but I'm still concerned how that was auto added?  I almost locked myself out of my machine.

Answer (score 13):

there is a command inside authorized_keys as follows.

```
cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys 
no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user \"ubuntu\" rather than the user \"root\".';echo;sleep 10"
```

remove this line and keep the ssh-rsa and key that comes after it.

save the file then try again.

Comment: I have edited the file and even rebooted but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Where do those commands prepended to the `authorized_keys` file come from?

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to address this is by using ssh's `-l` flag. Not by tampering with warning messages.

#### Example:

**Not working:**

```
$ sudo ssh -i *path/xxxxx.pem* n.n.n.n
Please login using xxxxx
```

**Working:**

```
$ sudo ssh -i keys/xxxxxx n.n.n.n -l ubuntu
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1021-aws x86_64)
```

**Note:** You are elevating your permission to execute access to the `.pem` file. Which means you are probably 'root'. The SSH connection wants you to **login** with that machine's **user name** in this case "ubuntu". So, passing the "-l" flag allows us to set that value.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Because it kept on annoying me I created this oneliner:

```
# sed -i -e 's/.*exit 142" \(.*$\)/\1/' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```